# How to move from one Activity to another in Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, android-intent

How do we move from one activity (Welcome) to another (Tutorial) by pressing a button?

Here is my Welcome.java file:

```
package com.rippledirectory;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Welcome extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome,
                container, false);
        return rootView;

        }

    }
    }
```

Here is my Tutorial.java:

```
package com.rippledirectory;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Tutorial extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutorial,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Here is my app Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.rippledirectory"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.3" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.rippledirectory.Welcome"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.rippledirectory.Tutorial"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tutorial"
        android:parentActivityName="com.rippledirectory.Welcome" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.rippledirectory.Welcome" />
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is really simple and basic question! Looks like need more study before making Android app.
Anyway, let  know the answer :)

First, make a Button in welcome.xml layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Second, declare Button object to Welcome.java.

```
private Button goTutorialBTN;
```

Third, impl Button object in Welcome.java.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        goTutorialBTN = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        goTutorialBTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Welcome.this, Tutorial.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below complete code-

welcome.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.demoproject.Welcome"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >


    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_move"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Move to Tutorial Activity"
        />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Welcome.java

```
package com.example.demoproject;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;

public class Welcome extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button btn_move;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        btn_move=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_move);
        btn_move.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.e("Button Click", "---->");
                Intent i=new Intent(Welcome.this,Tutorial.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Demomanifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.demoproject.Welcome"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.demoproject.Tutorial"/>
</application>
```

Hope this helps you !!!!

If its not working let me know i will try to help you more...!!

Comment: When I run the app on my device (Nexus 7 2013) it shows Unfortunately, myapp has stopped! Please Help! :/

Comment: did you got any error on logcat? please share that error.

Comment: Hi, I tried,but it now shows a blank page. Can you please again write the intent code? I want to move from one activity (Welcome) to another (States).

Comment: And one more error it is showing on Welcome.this. The error says. "No enclosing instance of the type Welcome is accessible in scope". Please help me in both the cases. Thanks! :)